# Sql Server LocalDB Generates good plan; Express bad one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2014, I'm dynamically creating scratch tables like:

```
create TABLE [dbo].[##jimmy]
(
     [id] int primary key IDENTITY(1,1),
     [Column1] varchar(4000) NULL, 
     [MayBeManyMoreLikeThis] varchar(4000)
)
```

Then, I bulk insert (in current sample 18K rows) & update (sometimes most) rows:

```
update ##jimmy 
set [Column1] = null 
where id in (1,2.....)
```

The updates are at least twice as fast running against `LocalDB` than against SQL Server Express.

The plan generated by `LocalDB` looks like this:

[image: Good Plan]

The plan generated by Express looks like:

[image: Bad Plan]

I can find no helpful table/query hints (option(hash join) on the Express query made it worse; sort operation remained). I'm wondering if there's any way to make Express omit that unnecessary sort operation.

Comment: Why are you creating ##global and not #local temp tables? Also try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the `UPDATE` statement. It's possible - depending on parameterization settings - you have a plan cached in Express for a small number of values and it's being re-used for the large values.

Comment: What version of SQL is LocalDB?  Express is limited to 4 cores and 1 gb.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand: These 2 tasks are done at different points in a larger system; different connections.  Just checked; same exact plan for local temp.

Comment: @Blam: Both are 2014.  LocalDB will have the same limitation as Express, no?  In any case I would think the plan difference is the key, no?